# Add value to or change values of a subset of rows in a column in R

Tags: r, replace, matching, partial

I've merged an exported data.frame of updated EPA measurements to an existing data.frame of values for previous years after cleaning and formatting the new data to match the old, but when I try to sum a set of values from the merged data with `aggregate`, the calculation ends up off because the newer data lists count codes differently (oddly, they are the same in the web database), i.e.: "6037" instead of "06037". (This is a non-problem for other observations that retain 5 digit codes, i.e.: don't begin with zero)

simply using:

```
df <- subset(df, column == c("6037", "06037" & column == "value")
```

somehow drops some of the columns with "6037" (but not all) and using:

```
df <- subset(df, column == grepl("^6037", df[column, ]) & column == "value")
```

takes too long because there are ~ 8 million observations

Is there a tidy way I can search for any observations in a column that have 4 rather than 5 characters i.e.: "6037" instead of "06037" and replace those values with the same string of characters with a zero added as the first character in the sequence for all those values?

Thanks in advance (first post, BTW. R newbie.),
Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say `x <- c("6037","06037","06037","6037","06037","06037")` is your column. We can use `nchar` to pick elements of length 4, and then replace...

```
ind4 <- sapply(x, nchar)==4
x[ind4] <- paste0("0", x[ind4])
x
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks. This will be super handy in the future. Still dropping rows when I subset and summing incorrectly on aggregate for these values only unfortunately, back to the drawing board.

Comment: You are welcome. Pls don't forget to accept your favorite answer by clicking on the check mark to the left...

Answer (score 2):

Use `formatC`:

```
df$column <- formatC(as.numeric(df$column), width=5, flag="0")
```

`width=5` specifies that the column is meant to have 5 digits; `flag=0` that the leading digit should be 0 if it would be blank.

Comment: Actually, using as.numeric turned the 5 character width numbers into dot notation.